# Razor Page and Bootstrap, no space between links

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I don't know why after adding the if statement a margin/space between my action links disappears. I'm pretty sure that a HTML looks the same with or without @if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) (from the admin perspective). I'm using bootstrap 4.1.

```
<section id="sec5">
  <div class="container pt-5">
    <div class="table-responsive-sm mb-3">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th class="text-right">Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var u in Model)
        {
          <tr>
            <td>@u.Name</td>
            <td class="text-right">
              @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
              {
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = u.SpecialityId }, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary" })
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = u.SpecialityId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
              }
            </td>
          </tr>
        }
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

E:

https://jsfiddle.net/xoduf1sp/5/

Comment: Could u add the actual HTML code your razor-page does generate? Im having a suspicion what the problem is, but i need the real HTML code to check.

Comment: @FabianSchöner https://jsfiddle.net/xoduf1sp/5/
I didn't see the difference in html because my browser formated it. With the if statement links have a 'white space' between them <a>link1</a> <a>link</a>.

Comment: I added my comment as answer so you can accept it so the question becomes resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example both the second link follows the first link immediately. 
If i add a linebreak between them in the html the usual inline element gap appears.

Maybe your if clause does somehow elimitate whitespace/linebreak characters between the two links?

Was:

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">Edit</a><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a>
```

Should be:

```
<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">Edit</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/xoduf1sp/7.